# failed to read artifact descriptor for org.primefaces.themes;bootstrap:jar:1.0.10

Tags: eclipse, maven, primefaces

I am trying to add Primefaces to my Maven project.
When I loaded my page I got following error message:

```
Error loading css, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-bootstrap" library
```

From other posts, I understood I also have to add the bootstrap theme.

But when I add the dependency fro the bootstrap theme and I get a red cross on my `pom.xml`.

See screenshot :

[image]

Here is the `pom.xml`, you can see the repository and the dependency for primefaces:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>primefaces-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
       <version>6.1</version>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The error message is :

> failed to read artifact descriptor for org.primefaces.themes;bootstrap:jar:1.0.10

Comment: Which view does the screenshot show (_Package/Project Explorer_, _Navigator_, ...)? Look in the _Proplems_ view for the error message.

Comment: @howlger I edited my question because my first problem is solved (issue was the version) . Now I am facing a new issue : I am trying to add dependency for PF Bootstrap theme but pom.xml is showing red cross when I do so

Comment: Look in the _Problems_ view for the error marker of the `pom.xml` file and add the error message to your question, please.

Comment: @howlger the problem is : failed to read artifact descriptor for org.primefaces.themes;bootstrap:jar:1.0.10

Comment: The search Google for similar issues... lots of info if you just post the error in there